# problem during Twitter+oauth integratin?

Tags: objective-c, ios4, twitter

i am using twitter + oauth for twitter integration in iphone. when i run the app. i got message such as "sorry that page doesn't exist!" even though i am using following things.

self.requestTokenURL = [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://twitter.com/oauth/request_token"];
        self.accessTokenURL = [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://twitter.com/oauth/access_token"];
        self.authorizeURL = [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://twitter.com/oauth/authorize"];

can Anybody has Solution??

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use

- [http://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/post/oauth/request_token)
- [http://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/post/oauth/access_token)
- [http://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/oauth/authorize)

You are missing the third level api domain in your URLs.

Comment: Thanks SB, The problem is that i am running myapp in simulator, so it is not showing me.   When i tried it on iphone it is working well.